# The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Alguien sabe porque me genera este error? la unica fecha que tengo es para el filtro del WHERE, aca el codigo

```
exec Informe_Cartera_PRUE '2019','01','26'
USE [Porcisoft_Cliente_PDV0]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Informe_Cartera_PV]    Script Date: 27/02/2019 06:30:36 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Informe_Cartera_PRUE] @Year  NVARCHAR(4), 
                                             @Month NVARCHAR(2),
                                             @Day   NVARCHAR(2)
AS 
     SET NOCOUNT ON; 
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Cartera]
     ([codigo]        [CHAR](30)      NULL, 
      [Codbodega]     [CHAR](30)      NULL,
      [NombreCliente] [NVARCHAR](200) NULL,
      [Consecutivo]   [CHAR](20)      NULL, 
      [codtipodcto]   [NVARCHAR](5)   NULL,
      [Totalgeneral]  [NUMERIC](20,2) NULL,
      [Saldo]  [NUMERIC](20,2) NULL,       
     )
     ON [PRIMARY];

--Apartado
INSERT INTO #Cartera
SELECT FA0.Codigo,FA0.Codbodega,RTRIM (FA0.nombre )+' '+ RTRIM(FA0.Nombre1) +' '+RTRIM( FA0.Apellido)+' '+RTRIM(FA0.Apellido1) AS NombreCliente,FA0.Consecutivo,FA0.codtipodcto,FA0.Totalgeneral,
(FA0.Totalgeneral-((IsNull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)))) as Saldo
FROM (

SELECT S0.Nombre,S0.Nombre1,S0.Apellido,S0.Apellido1,S0.Telefono1,S0.EsCliente,S0.EsEmpleado,
       F0.tiporeferencia,F0.Codigo,F0.consecutivo,F0.Referencia,F0.Fecha,F0.Fechavence,F0.codtipodcto,F0.Totalgeneral,F0.codbodega
FROM PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencfacturas F0 INNER JOIN tblsocio_negocios S0 ON F0.codigo=S0.codigo
WHERE F0.Fecha<=@Year+'/'+@Month+'/'+@Day)AS FA0 LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT A1.codtipodcto,A0.Codigo,A1.Factura,SUM(A1.Valor)AS Valor,SUM(A1.Retencion)AS Retencion
FROM PRAPORCIPOS.dbo.tblencabonosfactura A0 INNER JOIN tblmvtoabonosfactura A1 ON A0.documento=A1.documento
WHERE A0.Fecha<=@Year+'/'+@Month+'/'+@Day
GROUP BY  A1.codtipodcto,A0.Codigo,A1.Factura) AB0 ON FA0.consecutivo=AB0.factura AND FA0.codtipodcto=AB0.codtipodcto
where (FA0.Totalgeneral-((IsNull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)))) > 1 OR (FA0.Totalgeneral-((IsNull(AB0.Valor,0)+IsNull(AB0.Retencion,0)))) < -1 and FA0.tiporeferencia <> 'FAP' and FA0.codtipodcto <> 'FAP' 
order by Codbodega asc, nombrecliente asc

select * from #Cartera
```

Comment: Tu motor de base de datos, usa la fecha en formato 'yyyy/MM/dd'? Tal vez por eso te está dando el error...

Comment: Cuál es el tipo de dato de F0.Fecha?? Según la documentación de Microsoft DATEFORMAT ydm no es compatible con los tipos de datos date , datetime2 y datetimeoffset(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) . A eso sumarle que no vas a poder ejecutar el procedimiento y dar formato a la fecha si el dateformat está fuera del procedimiento.

Comment: F0.Fecha es de tipo Datetime, pero no veo el porque se genera el error

Comment: Antes que nada prueba hacer un `CONVERT(DATETIME, @Year+'/'+@Month+'/'+@Day)` a ver si efectivamente los parámetros se pueden mapear en un `datetime`

Comment: me saca error en la conversion, pero me dice que el error es por el '/', ya que no lo puede convertir